# Why is honcho forking recursively?

Tags: python, heroku

This used to work for me:

http://www.radekdostal.com/content/heroku-running-multiple-python-processes-single-dyno-using-honcho

However, today I pushed a new version and honcho started forking like crazy:

`honcho -f ProcfileHoncho start
21:15:09 web.1  | started with pid 8
21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | started with pid 11
21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | started with pid 14
21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | started
with pid 17
21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | 21:15:09 web.1  | started with pid 20`

I didn't change anything relevant like the `Procfile` or `ProcfileHoncho`, but it was a while so maybe a new version of Honcho is to blame.

What's going on here?

Comment: Some more google keywords: process processes recursive

Answer (score 1):

This forks like crazy:

```
# Procfile
web: honcho -f ProcfileHoncho start
```

But this works:

```
# Procfile
web: honcho start -f ProcfileHoncho
```

So I guess in a recent version of Honcho it started caring where option parameters are, before or after `start`, and if they're wrong - it ignores `-f ProcfileHoncho` and reads `Procfile`, which tells it to open a new Honcho...

Hope this helps anyone.